# iOS App: AVFoundation Video camera recording delegates

Tags: ios, ipad, delegates, camera

I am trying to develop an app that records the video using the rear camera.
I want the video to be tweaked (adding overlay image, green screen) before saving it to a file.

I am using AVFoundation, and have researched anywhere, but I still cant make the correct codes to preview and record (without the tweaking)

Some codes that Iget from the internet use BufferDelegate, the rest are using RecordingDelegate.

Do I need to use both to achieve what I want? or is it just one ofthem?

Could you please pinpoint me how I can achieve this?